# Fast iterative changes in pandas dataframe groups

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I have a large pandas dataframe that consists of users, the products that each user bought and product prices.

The code I am using is showed below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

# Create Dataframe randomly
product_list = ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5', 'P6', 'P7', 'P8', 'P9', 'P10', 'P11', 'P12']
user_list = ['U1', 'U2', 'U3', 'U4', 'U5', 'U6', 'U7', 'U8', 'U9', 'U10']
price_list = [50, 90, 100]

# Create random transactions
transactions = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(user_list, 200))
transactions['item'] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(product_list, 200))
transactions['quantity'] = 1
transactions['price'] = np.random.choice([50, 90, 100], 200)
transactions.columns = ['user', 'item', 'quantity', 'price']
transactions['suggested_price'] = 0

# Create groups to apply suggested discount
grouped = transactions.groupby(["user", "item"])

# Apply suggested discount
for key, group in grouped:
    transactions.set_value(
        group.index, 'suggested_discount', np.random.random())
```

My biggest problem with this code is the performance of the last block of code that applies the suggested discount to each user (customer). The original dataframe has over 6 million rows.

Also, one thing I noticed is that the slowest step is when I change the value of the groups, i.e., the line:

```
transactions.set_value(
            group.index, 'suggested_discount', np.random.random())
```

In the original code there are other steps before this line of code.

I was not expecting that changing the values of the group columns would be so slow. Is there a better, faster implementation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that instead of `np.random.random()` you have a function that takes arguments from the price and suggested price columns, you should try to either use `apply` or `transform` or `agg` to those columns. Scalar operations instead of for loop will be much quicker.

For example, first set the `user` and `item` fields as indexes, then you can directly set a value from the grouped data to that new dataframe:

```
tr=transactions.set_index(["user","item"]) 
tr["suggested discount"]=transactions.groupby(["user", "item"])[["price","suggested_price"]].apply(pd.Series.sum)
```

Anyhow, the key is not using a for loop.